# How to group two-dimensional arrays and convert them into objects with key names

Tags: javascript

I would like to convert a variable from start to goal as follows

```
var start = [
{companyName: "google", expenseTitle: "transaction fee", itemName: "test", number: 1, unit: "個",price:1000000},
{companyName: "google", expenseTitle: "transaction fee", itemName: "test", number: 1, unit: "個",price:1000},
{companyName: "Apple", expenseTitle: "transaction fee2", itemName: "test2", number: 1, unit: "個",price:5500000},
{companyName: "Apple", expenseTitle: "transaction fee2", itemName: "test2", number: 1, unit: "個",price:1000}
]
```

```
        var goal = [{
            companyName: "google",
            expenseTitle: "transaction fee",
            arrays: [
                ["test", "", 1, "個", 1000000],
                ["test", "", 1, "個", 1000]
            ]
        }, {
            companyName: "Apple",
            expenseTitle: "transaction fee2",
            arrays: [
                ["test2", "", 1, "個", 5500000],
                ["test2", "", 1, "個", 1000]
            ]
        }];
```

I have a feeling that we can use the Map() method once we have converted it to an associative array of objects.
If you can tell me if that approach is the right one to begin with, or if you have a better way to go about it, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got the logic properly, something, like that, might work:

```js
const src = [{companyName:"google",expenseTitle:"transaction fee",itemName:"test",number:1,unit:"個",price:1000000},{companyName:"google",expenseTitle:"transaction fee",itemName:"test",number:1,unit:"個",price:1000},{companyName:"Apple",expenseTitle:"transaction fee2",itemName:"test2",number:1,unit:"個",price:5500000},{companyName:"Apple",expenseTitle:"transaction fee2",itemName:"test2",number:1,unit:"個",price:1000}],

    result = Object.values(src.reduce((r, {companyName, expenseTitle, ...rest}) => {
      r[companyName] = r[companyName] || {companyName, expenseTitle, arrays:[]}
      r[companyName].arrays.push(Object.values(rest))
      return r
    }, {}))
    
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **reduce** method, and use the single output value;

```
const result = start.reduce((acc, el) => {
    const i = acc.findIndex(e => e.companyName === el.companyName && e.expenseTitle === el.expenseTitle);
    const arr = [el.itemName, el.number, el.unit, el.price];

    if (i >= 0) {
        acc[i].arrays.push(arr);
    }
    else {
        acc.push({
            companyName: el.companyName,
            expenseTitle: el.expenseTitle,
            arrays: [arr]
        })
    }

    return acc;
}, []);
```

Basically what it does is try to find in the accumulator an existing element with the same *companyName* and *expenseTitle*. If it find one, then push the needed information into the arrays property. If not, creates a new element.

Comment: Your code implements O(n²)-time complexity algorithm (due to `.findIndex()` nested within `.reduce()`) which leads to [certain performance loss](https://jsbench.me/b3kc9jy8pn/1) compared to O(n)-time algorithm (single pass)

Comment: Thanks mate! I’m much better developer now!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses the companyName and expenseTitle as keys of an object/dictionary to makes it easy to group them.

```
var start = [
{companyName: "google", expenseTitle: "transaction fee", itemName: "test", number: 1, unit: "個",price:1000000},
{companyName: "google", expenseTitle: "transaction fee", itemName: "test", number: 1, unit: "個",price:1000},
{companyName: "Apple", expenseTitle: "transaction fee2", itemName: "test2", number: 1, unit: "個",price:5500000},
{companyName: "Apple", expenseTitle: "transaction fee2", itemName: "test2", number: 1, unit: "個",price:1000}
]

var goal = {};

start.forEach(item => {
   const key = `${item.companyName} | ${item.expenseTitle}`;

   if (goal[key] === undefined) {
      goal[key] = [];
      goal[key].push([item.name, item.number, item.unit, item.price]);
   }
   else {
      console.log('with key', goal);
      goal[key].push([item.name, item.number, item.unit, item.price]);
   }
})

// Result in goal
console.log(goal);
```